# lack of account separation in Mac 10.9

Tags: macos, permissions

I am confused by some behavior I see in Mac OS 10.9 or its underlying BSD.

I am an administrator and wanted to add an account for a family member. They're not savvy, so I want to make sure they cannot accidentally delete my files, i.e. standard UNIX account separation.

So I created a standard (not admin) account through the Preferences > Users. Experimenting, I was surprised to find that when I created a file in my home directory (the permissions of which I changed to `drwx------`, i.e. mode `700`) the new user could still `cd` into this directory (!) and delete my files!

I see that the new user is in group "staff" which is also the group associated with my home directory. But doesn't my mode 700 mean that the group is irrelevant, and the user must be me, to see and delete files therein?

--Confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your description correctly; did you change the permissions on your home directory to 700, or on the new file inside your home? If you set them on the file, that's irrelevant to deleting the file -- file permissions regulate access to the file's contents, and moving, renaming, and deleting the file don't change its contents. Instead, moving renaming and deleting all change the contents of the directory the file is in, and hence depend only on the directory's permissions.

Mind you, nobody other than you should have write access to your home directory (needed to move, rename, and delete files in it). Check its permissions with the command `ls -lde ~`:

```
$ ls -lde ~
drwxr-xr-x@ 61 gordon  staff  2074 Dec 18 09:45 /Users/gordon
 0: group:everyone deny delete
```

My home (shown above) has standard OS X permissions -- mode is 755 (only I have write access, group and others have read and execute only) and there's also an access control entry denying anyone (including me) the ability to delete it. Access controls entries override the regular unix permissions, so it's possible that you have an ACL that's letting your other user delete things from your home.

Comment: My home directory, output of ls -lde ~: `iMac:~ steve$ ls -lde ~
drwx------  95 steve  staff  3230 Dec 21 00:25 /Volumes/UpstairsExternal/steve` in other words I have tried to lock all users but me out of my home directory.  "Access controls entries override the regular unix permissions" -- Very surprising. I am trying to wrap my mind around how that could be implemented. I thought the MacOS was built atop the primitive capabilities provided by BSD. Is there a capabilities or ACL system somehow beneath the file permissions bits? First I have heard of that.

Comment: @user1416227: ACLs are an extension to the basic unix mode bits; the reason they take precedence is simply the order the kernel checks for access: it runs through the access control entries in numeric order; if it finds one that applies to the access being attempted, it uses that; if not, it checks the basic POSIX mode bits. But in your case, there's no ACL on your home directory, so that's not what's causing the issue. One random thought: did the new user somehow get the same UID as your account? Try `id steve` and `id otheraccount` to check.

Comment: My UID is 501 and the new user has UID 503.

Comment: The only other possibility I can think of: is your home directory on a secondary volume (i.e. not the startup volume)? If so, ownership might be being ignored on it (see [Apple KB #PH10670](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH10670)), in which case files on it are treated as owned by everyone. If this is the problem, follow the instructions in the KB article to turn this option off. I that's not it... I'm stumped.

Comment: yes! I recently moved my home directory to an external hard drive. Will check...

Comment: The external hard drive did not have the "ignore ownership of this volume" box checked. The disk's permissions were "me" read+write, "everyone" read only, and some third party as "read+write". The o/s announced it was "fetching..." the identity of the third party, but this resolution never completes. Whatever user that is, I changed it's permissions on the disk to read only. Then I checked that the user with UID =503 can delete files in my home directory; it is still possible.

Comment: Was the "ignore ownership" box checked when you copied your home folder to that disk? If so, it still won't have a real owner assigned. If that's not it, what format is the volume in, and does the `mount` command show it's mounted with any unusual options?